# Add a column with mean values for groups based on another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

So, basically I have a df that has in one column the different areas for each instance and in another two columns the amount they produce.

Something like this:

| entity | area | prod_a | prod_b |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | A | 1 | 3 |
| 002 | B | 2 | 4 |
| 003 | A | 2 | 6 |
| 004 | C | 7 | 2 |
| 005 | C | 4 | 8 |
| 006 | B | 6 | 5 |

I want to add two new columns with the **total mean** for each king of production (`prod_a` and `prod_b`) discriminated by **area**.

For example:

| entity | area | prod_a | prod_b | mean prod_a for the area | mean prod_b for the area |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | A | 1 | 3 | 1.5 | 4.5 |
| 002 | B | 2 | 4 | 4 | 2.5 |
| 003 | A | 2 | 6 | 1.5 | 4.5 |
| 004 | C | 7 | 2 | 5.5 | 5 |
| 005 | C | 4 | 8 | 5.5 | 5 |
| 006 | B | 6 | 1 | 4 | 2.5 |

I've already tried a lot a ideas, but neither of them worked, I'm a little lost here, so if anyone could help me it would be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can use [`groupby transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) to calculate the `mean` on the desired columns then [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) back to the initial DataFrame to add the newly created columns:

```
df = df.join(
    df.groupby('area')[['prod_a', 'prod_b']]
        .transform('mean')  # Calculate the mean for each group
        .rename(columns='mean {} for the area'.format)  # Rename columns 
)
```

`df`:

| entity | area | prod_a | prod_b | mean prod_a for the area | mean prod_b for the area |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | A | 1 | 3 | 1.5 | 4.5 |
| 002 | B | 2 | 4 | 4 | 4.5 |
| 003 | A | 2 | 6 | 1.5 | 4.5 |
| 004 | C | 7 | 2 | 5.5 | 5 |
| 005 | C | 4 | 8 | 5.5 | 5 |
| 006 | B | 6 | 5 | 4 | 4.5 |

---

Setup:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'entity': ['001', '002', '003', '004', '005', '006'],
    'area': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'B'], 
    'prod_a': [1, 2, 2, 7, 4, 6],
    'prod_b': [3, 4, 6, 2, 8, 5]
})
```